# How to adapt TSP to solve currency arbitrage

Tags: qiskit

I came across Qiskit's 'Max-Cut and Traveling Salesman Problem' and would like to adapt it to currency arbitrage problem.

I have assigned currencies as nodes in the code below, and written the currency exchange rates in a matrix.

I'm not sure whether the edges are being assigned to the exchange rate, and what is causing the error?

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

Comment: can you paste all the code here, not screeen shot, so I can quickly try it out.

Answer (score 0):

The code is looking for the "weight" as an attribute of edge, in this case each edge being a dictionary of attributes. It is failing in get_item call as its trying to get this item from the dictionary there but instead you have a float, i.e. the weight directly. Its expecting weights to be accessed this way

> graph.edges[w, v]["weight"]

Taking a look at this [routine that builds out a random TSP](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-optimization/blob/3283e4ce655eaccbceefc5d3980b595a1dc5a3ad/qiskit_optimization/applications/tsp.py#L117-L137) may be helpful too as it shows the way things are expected as well.